# Trying to connect to webserver on pi (as access point)

Tags: raspbian, access-point

I have a raspberry pi which is running some webpage on a port.
The pi is accessible through it's wifi (configured as access point).

Everything works fine, when I connect my PC to the ssid hosted by the pi, I can navigate to : and I can see the content my pi is sharing.

When I try to do the same on my phone, the page won't load.
I can see that I get an IP address on my phone.
when I go to a browser (chrome) and navigate to:
http://192.168.4.1:8000

it keeps searching forever, but never gives an error nor does it show the content of my webpage.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Sounds like a phone problem - not a Pi problem.

Comment: What a phone is it? What frequencies do you use?

Comment: A Samsung s7. Connected via 2.4ghz

Comment: I would first see if the pi and the phone are on the same subnet.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if the phone has no option called somewhat like "Intelligent Wi-Fi" enabled, which switches the connection to cellular if "Wi-Fi network is unstable". Of course, this is just speculation.